# Spring Cloud DataFlow RabbitMQ min-start-interval

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp, spring-cloud-dataflow

I want to start 50 Rabbit consumers as soon as I start the app and start more consumers each second if needed up to 500 consumers.

How can I set the `startConsumerMinInterval` for RabbitMQ in the `application.yaml` of the deployer? I found `startConsumerMinInterval` property in the [Spring AMQP](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#containerAttributes) documentation, but I can't find anything mentioning this property in the [binder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/_rabbitmq_binder.html#_rabbitmq_consumer_properties) documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those properties are not currently exposed by the binder.

You should open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit) to ask for a new feature.